# Can I bind an existing method to a LLVM Function* and use it from JIT-compiled code?

Tags: c++, jit, llvm

I'm toying around with the LLVM C++ API. I'd like to JIT compile code and run it.

However, I need to call a C++ method from said JIT-compiled code. Normally, LLVM treats method calls as function calls with the object pointer passed as the first argument, so calling shouldn't be a problem. The real problem is to get that function into LLVM.

As far as I can see, it's possible to use external linkage for functions and get it by its name. Problem is, since it's a C++ method, its name is going to be mangled, so I don't think it's a good idea to go that way.

Making the `FunctionType` object is easy enough. But from there, how can I inform LLVM of my method and get a `Function` object for it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The dudes from the LLVM mailing list were [helpful enough to provide a better solution](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmdev/2010-June/032661.html). They didn't say how to get the pointer from the method to the function, but I've already figured out this part so it's okay.

**EDIT** A clean way to do this is simply to wrap your method into a function:

```
int Foo_Bar(Foo* foo)
{
    return foo->bar();
}
```

Then use `Foo_Bar`'s address instead of trying to get `Foo::bar`'s. Use `llvm::ExecutionEngine::addGlobalMapping` to add the mapping as shown below.

As usual, the simplest solution has some interesting benefits. For instance, it works with virtual functions without a hiccup. (But it's so much less entertaining. The rest of the answer is kept for historical purposes, mainly because I had a lot of fun poking at the internals of my C++ runtime. Also note that it's non-portable.)

---

You'll need something along these lines to figure the address of a method (be warned, that's a dirty hack that probably will only be compatible with the Itanium ABI):

```
template<typename T>
const void* void_cast(const T& object)
{
    union Retyper
    {
        const T object;
        void* pointer;
        Retyper(T obj) : object(obj) { }
    };

    return Retyper(object).pointer;
}

template<typename T, typename M>
const void* getMethodPointer(const T* object, M method) // will work for virtual methods
{
    union MethodEntry
    {
        intptr_t offset;
        void* function;
    };

    const MethodEntry* entry = static_cast<const MethodEntry*>(void_cast(&method));

    if (entry->offset % sizeof(intptr_t) == 0) // looks like that's how the runtime guesses virtual from static
        return getMethodPointer(method);

    const void* const* const vtable = *reinterpret_cast<const void* const* const* const>(object);
    return vtable[(entry->offset - 1) / sizeof(void*)];
}

template<typename M>
const void* getMethodPointer(M method) // will only work with non-virtual methods
{
    union MethodEntry
    {
        intptr_t offset;
        void* function;
    };

    return static_cast<const MethodEntry*>(void_cast(&method))->function;
}
```

Then use `llvm::ExecutionEngine::addGlobalMapping` to map a function to the address you've gotten. To call it, pass it your object as the first parameter, and the rest as usual. Here's a quick example.

```
class Foo
{
    void Bar();
    virtual void Baz();
};

class FooFoo : public Foo
{
    virtual void Baz();
};

Foo* foo = new FooFoo;

const void* barMethodPointer = getMethodPointer(&Foo::Bar);
const void* bazMethodPointer = getMethodPointer(foo, &Foo::Baz); // will get FooFoo::Baz

llvm::ExecutionEngine* engine = llvm::EngineBuilder(module).Create();

llvm::Function* bar = llvm::Function::Create(/* function type */, Function::ExternalLinkage, "foo", module);
llvm::Function* baz = llvm::Function::Create(/* function type */, Function::ExternalLinkage, "baz", module);
engine->addGlobalMapping(bar, const_cast<void*>(barMethodPointer)); // LLVM always takes non-const pointers
engine->addGlobalMapping(baz, const_cast<void*>(bazMethodPointer));
```

Comment: Would you mind to show us how you resolved the issue in the end. I'm struggling with the same problem.

Comment: @FFox: sure. I've edited the answer to provide a helpful example.

Comment: @zneak, in the function type you pass to `llvm::Function::Create` what type did you use for the first argument (the object pointer)? did you use void*?

Comment: @lurscher, no, because that would be a real hassle to work with. The pattern is to make a specialization of the class `StructType<typename T, bool xcompile>` with `T` being your struct and implement the `get` method there. You can then use `llvm::StructType<MyStruct>::get(context)` to get the type, and getting the pointer type to it is then trivial. See [here](http://pastebin.com/JbzdPDZt) for an example implementation.

Comment: Do you know a way to do this with the more modern `orc` Jit api? ([question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69742580/how-to-resolve-symbols-that-reside-in-the-current-session-when-constructing-a-o))

Answer (score 8):

One way is a C wrapper around the desired method, i.e.

```
extern "C" {
  void wrapped_foo(bar *b, int arg1, int arg2) {
    b->foo(arg1, arg2);
  }
}
```

The `extern "C"` bit makes the function use C calling conventions and prevents any name mangling. See http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html#faq-32.6 for details on C/C++ interop including `extern "C"`

You should also probably be able to get the address of the function in your C++ code and then store that address in a global known to LLVM.

Comment: I thought there could be a more straightforward way.

Answer (score 5):

Huh, using the non-standard `dladdr` and a ridiculously convoluted and unsafe way to cast method pointers to void pointers, there seems to be a way to obtain the name of a method from its pointer.

This is certainly more dangerous than firearms. Don't do this at home (or at work, for that matter).

C++ forbids to cast method pointers to void* (which is required by `dladdr` to work) even with the almighty C cast, but you can cheat that.

```
#include <string>
#include <dlfcn.h>

template<typename T>
static void* voidify(T method)
{
    asm ("movq %rdi, %rax"); // should work on x86_64 ABI compliant platforms
}

template<typename T>
const char* getMethodName(T method)
{
    Dl_info info;
    if (dladdr(voidify(method), &info))
        return info.dli_sname;
    return "";
}
```

From there:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << getMethodName(&Foo::bar) << std::endl;
    // prints something like "_ZN3Foo3barEv"
}
```

...aaaand you should be able to use that symbol name with LLVM. But it won't work with virtual methods (another good reason to not use it).

**EDIT** Hacking much, much deeper into how virtual method pointers are handled, I've put together a more elaborate function that works for them, too. Only the most courageous of you should [follow this link](http://pastebin.com/aSnvdeUK).

Comment: @Paul Nathan: it did emit a few warnings, though ("control reaches end of non-void function"). I've _beautified_ it to integrate better with C++.